# How can I make HighCharts HeatMap annotations visible?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to add annotation to the heat map chart but it does not seem to show.  Appreciate if you would be able to help.

See screenshot

Shape or callout is not visible, the label is visible though. Not sure what I'm missing.

Please assist. Thanks, Lisa

screenshot
[Heatmapwithscatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUcE2.png)

this is what I want to achieve:
[Model Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebaMI.png)

Attaching the test code:

```
$('#container').highcharts(
    {
            chart: 
        {
            
            type: 'heatmap', marginTop: 50, marginBottom: 50, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', plotBackgroundColor: 
            { 
                linearGradient: {x1: 1, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                    stops: [
                                [0.10, 'rgb(240, 59, 9)'], 
                                [0.40, 'rgb(255, 224, 80)'], 
                                [0.60, 'rgb(245, 202, 2)'], 
                                [0.85, 'rgb(4, 148, 25)'], 
                                [1, 'rgb(13, 163, 35)']
                        ]
            }
        },  
        xAxis: {
                    categories: [0,1,2,3,4,5] ,   lineWidth: 0, min: 0, max: 5, title: {text: 'Inherent Risk', style: {fontWeight: 'bold'}},
                    labels: 
                    {   
                                formatter: function()
                        {   
                                    if(this.value == 5 ) return 'High';
                            else if(this.value == 3 ) return 'Medium';
                            else if(this.value == 1 ) return 'Low';
                            }
                            }
                },
        yAxis:  
        {reversed: true,
                categories: [5,4,3,2,1,0], lineWidth: 0, min: 0, max: 5 , title: { text: 'Control Environment', style: { fontWeight: 'bold' }},
                labels: 
                {
                            formatter: function()
                    {
                                if(this.value == 5 ) return 'Weak';
                        else if(this.value == 3 ) return 'Elevated Attention';
                        else if(this.value == 1 ) return 'Strong';
                            }
                        }
        },
        colorAxis: { min: 0, max: 5, minColor: 'transparent', maxColor: 'transparent'  },
        tooltip: 
        {enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: { scatter: {   
                                    dataLabels: { 
                                                      enabled: true,
                                                                      useHTML: true,
                                                           style: {
                                                                        color: 'blue',
                                                                          textOutline: 'none',
                                                                          fontWeight: 'bold',
                                                                    fontSize: 11,
                                                                            cursor: 'pointer'
                                                                     },


                                                           },
                                    
                                    allowPointSelect: true,  marker: { fillColor: 'blue' ,  lineColor: 'black', fillOpacity:0.7}
                                 }
                         },
            legend: {enabled: false, align: 'right', layout: 'vertical', verticalAlign: 'middle'},
        credits: { enabled: false},
            series: [
            {   

                type: 'heatmap', borderWidth: 1, 
                data: [
                        [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 2], [0, 3, 3], [0, 4, 4], [0, 5, 5],  
                        [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 3], [1, 4, 4], [1, 5, 5], 
                        [2, 0, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [2, 3, 3], [2, 4, 4], [2, 5, 5], 
                        [3, 0, 0], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [3, 4, 4], [3, 5, 5],
                        [4, 0, 0], [4, 1, 1], [4, 2, 2], [4, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [4, 5, 5], 
                        [5, 0, 0], [5, 1, 1], [5, 2, 2], [5, 3, 3], [5, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]
                       ],
                    dashStyle: 'Dot'
        
             },
                {
                    name: 'Scatter', type: 'scatter', 
                data: [[3,1.5,1,0056],
                    [3, 3.02, 2, 1338],
                    [3, 3.06, 3, 1176],
                    [0, 0, 4, 1221],
                    [0, 0, 5, 1517]]
                }],
        annotations: [{
                useHTML:true, visible: true,
                    labels: [{
                        point: this.point,
                text: 'call',
                        shape: 'callout'
               }],
             labelOptions: {
                 borderRadius: 5,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 197, 0.7)',
                 borderWidth: 1,
                 borderColor: '#AAA'
             }
            }]
                
        });
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @LCY, I've tried to reproduce the issue, but annotations seem to work as expected with heatmap. Please check this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z1kyfq3a/ and try to adapt it to show the problem.

Comment: Thank you for responding back. I tried adapting your code, but i cannot still make it work.

Comment: also, i'm passing 4 elements but is seems to capture only the first 2 elements data: [[3,1.5,1,0056],
 [3, 3.02, 2, 1338],
 [3, 3.06, 3, 1176],
 [0, 0, 4, 1221],
  [0, 0, 5, 1517]] and i wanted the label to show the 3rd element which is the rank - 0 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: also, how to make the point:    point: 'a1', - make it dynamic

Comment: First of all, please check the required data structure for a scatter series: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.data - only the first two array's elements are used. To show an annotation linked to a scatter point, you need to use point's id: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labels.point Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nem856t0/